# How do I intuitively interpret a sigmoidal neural network model?

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, theory, sigmoid

There are multiple sources, but they explain at a bit too high a level for me a to actually understand.

Here is my knowledge of how this model works;

We feed-forward information in prior layer's nodes using the weight * value. We do NOT use the sigmoid function here. This is because any hidden layers will force the value to be POSITIVE if we use the sigmoid function here. If it is always positive, then subsequent values can never be less than 0.5.

When we have fed forward to the output, we then use the sigmoid function on the output.

So in total we only use the sigmoid function on the output layer values only.

I will try to include a hopefully not terrible diagram

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIz1O.jpg

I have tested with my own code, and evidently it should not be the sigmoid function on every value and weight, but I am unsure if it is just the sum of weight*value

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have a set of features for your model. These features are independent variables which will be responsible for producing of the output. So features are the inputs and the predicted values are the outputs. This is indeed a function.

> It is easy to understand neural networks if we study them in terms of *functions*.

- First multiply the feature vector with the vector of weights. Meaning, the dot product of the both vectors must be produced.
- The dot product is a scalar if you have a single node ( neuron ). Apply sigmoid function on the product. The output is the final prediction.

The whole model could be expressed as a single composite function like,

```
y = sigmoid( dot( w , x ) )
```

Also understanding back propogation ( gradient descent ) for NN makes some intuition if we treat NN as functions.
In the above function,

- `sigmoid` : applies sigmoid activation function to the argument.
- `dot` : returns the dot product of two vectors.

Also, use vector notation as far as possible. It saves you from the confusion related with summations.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Activation functions serve an important role in neural network models: they can, given the choice of activation function, grant the network the capability to model non-linear datasets.

The example illustrated in the figure you posted (rendered below) will be limited to model linear problems where the output value is between 0 and 1 (the range of the sigmoidal function). However, the model would support non-linear datasets if the sigmoidal was applied to the two nodes in the middle. StackOverflow is not the place to discuss the theoretic foundation of why this works, instead I recommend looking into some light reading like this ebook: [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html) (no affiliation).

As a side note: the final, output layer of a network are sometimes instantiated as a simple sum, or a ReLU. This will widen the range of the network's output.

[image]

Comment: I see, so by manipulating activation functions depending on layer (output vs hidden), you can achieve very different results. I guess the most important feature I should keep an eye on is not completely limiting the range of values without reason in the hidden layers. Also, sorry about the incorrect posting spot, I am trying to apply this for a neuroevolutionary version of snake, and wasn't really sure if the math SO would be better as almost all NN are done on computers.

Comment: Correct. Choosing the optimal activation functions to use in the different hidden layers is an art, and will affect the model’s ability to “learn”. However, a network model tend to cope with constrained function ranges in the hidden layers given that the output layer has “enough” weights to produce the desired output values